# What are the names, or arguments of the atomic sentence "Max ate a cake" and "I ate a cake."

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

What are the names, or arguments of the atomic sentence

> Max ate a cake

and

> I ate a cake.

?

First of all, "Max" is definitely a name. But is "cake" a name? 
And in the second sentence, is "I" a name? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

"Cake" is an arbitrary name for a food, just as "Max" is an arbitrary name for a person. "I" isn't a name, but a pronoun. It can be replaced with a name (such as Max), but is not a name by itself.

Comment: First off, welcome to philosophy.se. There's more to what's going from a philosophy of language perspective than what you're suggesting especially in terms of "I". "I" is a difficult word to corral because it's not exactly substitutable in such an easy manner.